How to use trigonometric functions in .vdmrt files?
I am attempting to perform this operation in my program:
x := x + sin(y) * 0.05;
However the error Name 'sin(real)' is not in scope(3182) is returned.
I've tried to import what I think is the MATH module. using Import MATH;, which returns the error:
Expecting name:type in declaration(2228)
So I don't think I am going about this correctly.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

To use the MATH class, you first need to include the MATH.vdmrt file in your model (tools usually put this in the lib subfolder), and then you can refer to the functions within by saying MATH`sin(y) - note the backtick.
In the OO dialects (VDM-RT and VDM++) you don't need to import anything. You can access "public" members of the library directly. VDM-SL needs imports, but the syntax is not as you guessed.
